# calculate the duration period excluding weekend

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to calculate the duration between 2 dates; taking into consideration the opening hour 08:00 to 18:00 an excluding the weekend, not working date. how can I do. example:
First date: 4/8/23 12:40
Second date 7/8/23 10:07.

I need a formula to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the NETWORKDAYS formula? This allows you to calculate the difference between dates excluding holidays which you can reference a table of weekends.

Comment: Show a few examples of expected results. You need the result in days?, hours? minutes? Full day counted as 24 hours or 10 hours?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D1;D2;1)` worksheet function, described in [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28). Next to start and finish date, you need to fill in the kind of weekend days (saturday and sunday or other) and additionally you can even add extra holidays.

I just tried `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D1;D2;1)` from today up to February third and there seem to be 23 days indeed.